# Python : reduce the size of text file in bytes

Tags: python, filesize

I want to feed a text file like so:

```
  facefile = open("facebook.txt", "r")
```

into IBM's `Tone Analyzer`:

```
   demo_text = facefile.read()
   facefile.close()
   toneanalysis = json.dumps(tone_analyzer.tone(text=demo_text))
   tonefile = open("facetone.json", "w")
   print  >> tonefile, toneanalysis
   tonefile.close()
```

however, my scraped data (facefile) ammounts to `1.6 M`, and the tool supports up to `128 K` of text.

how do I **reduce a text file down to a fixed ammount of bytes**, so I can comply with the tool limits and keep the full data on my database as well?

Comment: Sure, easy, throw away everything but 148K of the file.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Dang, that was simple. And works in all cases. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "trimm"?

Comment: reduce I mean..

Comment: A quick glance at the documentation (https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/tone-analyzer/api/v3/?python#post-tone) reveals that the limit is 128K (not 148K).  It also reveals that this tool analyses sentences.  I would recommend splitting the file in parts (use the dot character in order to obtain complete sentences).